# В одной строке сделать текст слов разного цвета

Tags: html

Можно ли в html в одной строке сделать текст слов разного цвета? Например. 1 слово одним цветом, а второе - другим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6fRsA/

HTML:

```
<p>Первое слово <span>второе слово</span></p>
```

CSS:

```
p{
   color: #f00;
}
p span{
   color: #00f;
}
```